# GraphDB Workbench fails to load .owl ontology file from Protégé

Tags: ontology, protege, graphdb

I created an ontology with Protege, which is saved as an `.owl` file.

When I try to load it to GraphDB (8.9.0) through Workbench **Import** -> **RDF** -> **Upload RDF files (The supported RDF formats are .ttl .rdf .rj .n3 .nt .nq .trig .trix .brf .owl .jsonld, as well as their .gz versions and .zip archives)** I'm getting the error:

`RDF Parse Error: Content is not allowed in prolog. [line 1, column 1]`.

The full log:

```
01:00:37.877 [import-task-Accounting-1] ERROR o.e.r.rio.helpers.ParseErrorLogger - [Rio fatal] Content is not allowed in prolog. (1, 1)
01:00:37.879 [import-task-Accounting-1] ERROR c.o.f.impex.FileImportRunnableTask - RDF Parse Error 
org.eclipse.rdf4j.rio.RDFParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog. [line 1, column 1]
    at org.eclipse.rdf4j.rio.helpers.RDFParserHelper.reportFatalError(RDFParserHelper.java:442)
    at org.eclipse.rdf4j.rio.helpers.AbstractRDFParser.reportFatalError(AbstractRDFParser.java:783)
    at org.eclipse.rdf4j.rio.rdfxml.RDFXMLParser.reportFatalError(RDFXMLParser.java:1176)
    at org.eclipse.rdf4j.rio.rdfxml.RDFXMLParser.fatalError(RDFXMLParser.java:1315)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:180)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:400)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:327)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1472)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:994)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:841)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:770)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at org.eclipse.rdf4j.rio.rdfxml.RDFXMLParser.parse(RDFXMLParser.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.rdf4j.rio.rdfxml.RDFXMLParser.parse(RDFXMLParser.java:207)
    at org.eclipse.rdf4j.repository.util.RDFLoader.loadInputStreamOrReader(RDFLoader.java:286)
    at org.eclipse.rdf4j.repository.util.RDFLoader.load(RDFLoader.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.rdf4j.repository.base.AbstractRepositoryConnection.add(AbstractRepositoryConnection.java:329)
    at com.ontotext.trree.monitorRepository.MonitorRepositoryConnection.add(MonitorRepositoryConnection.java:177)
    at com.ontotext.trree.parallel.ParallelRDFLoader.add(ParallelRDFLoader.java:125)
    at com.ontotext.trree.parallel.ParallelRDFLoader.add(ParallelRDFLoader.java:54)
    at com.ontotext.forest.impex.ParallelAwareImporter.lambda$add$5(ParallelAwareImporter.java:107)
    at com.ontotext.forest.impex.ParallelAwareImporter.wrapInBeginCommit(ParallelAwareImporter.java:128)
    at com.ontotext.forest.impex.ParallelAwareImporter.add(ParallelAwareImporter.java:89)
    at com.ontotext.forest.impex.FileImportRunnableTask.load(FileImportRunnableTask.java:36)
    at com.ontotext.forest.impex.ImportRunnableTask.run(ImportRunnableTask.java:82)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:177)
    ... 29 common frames omitted
```

Any help/advice/hint will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is that GraphDB assumes that `.owl` files are written in XML, hence tries to parse them as such. However, as mentioned in the [OWL Conformance (2.2 Tool Conformance)](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/REC-owl2-conformance-20121211/#Tool_Conformance):

> A conformant OWL 2 tool *may* also accept ontology documents using other serializations, for example Turtle ...

In fact an OWL ontology definition can have 5 different valid formats: functional-style, RDF/XML, OWL/XML, Turtle and Manchester syntax. Protégé decided to use Turtle syntax for its `.owl` files, so GraphDB gets an error when trying to parse them as XML.

**Workaround:** Just change the file extension from `.owl` to `.ttl` and GraphDB will happily load it.

Comment: There are more than just those five (Trig, Trix, n-triples, json-ld, a few others). Protege allows their use and uses the commons-rdf-api and related implementations to support these formats. However, it's not Protege choosing the format for output - that choice is left to the user. The file extension is at best a suggestion.

Comment: As for the formats, you're right there are more than five, I just mentioned the ones proposed in the conformance document. As for Protégé, I'm new to it and didn't choose the output format, worked with the default settings.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that the file starts with a BOM character U+FEFF: error at line 1, column 1.This is a zero-width space used sometimes to mark a file as being in some Unicode representation, UTF-8, UTF-16LE, UTF-16BE. Can you share the first line of the file?
You can try removing the tag in the beginning of the file or by saving the file in Notepad++ with Encoding(Tab) > Encode in UTF-8:selected.

Comment: BOM, a space, or the file is not an XML file. Protege supports many different formats and in this case a non XML format might have been used.